# Find the minimum cost for given combinations

Tags: algorithm

**Example 1:**

I have a cost array of size n with values `[3,4,5,6,3,2,10]`.

I have 2 cluster with compatibility mentioned in arrays of size n

```
cluster 1 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
cluster 2 = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
```

`0` indicates that the cluster is not compatible and `1` indicates it is compatible.

I have to select minimum `m` selections from `cluster 1` and `cluster 2` such that they are compatible on both the clusters at least `m`.

Find the minimum cost for such selection. If such selection is not possible then return `-1`.

Answer for this example is : `13`

**Explanation:**

```
cost = [3,4,5,6,3,2,10]
cluster 1 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
cluster 2 = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0]
```

Pick indices [0,2,4,5] because cluster 1 has [0,4,5] = 3 selections and cluster 2 has [2,4,5] has 3 selections.

```
Cost is = cost[0] + cost[2] + cost[4] + cost[5] = 3+5+3+2 = 13
```

**My approach:**

First I have created a list for cluster 1 cost = `[3,4,0,6,3,2,0]` and cluster 2 cost = `[0,0,5,0,3,2,0]`
I have created another list that indicates the index position and the corresponding cost in sorted order by its cost:

cluster 1 = `[[5,2], [0,3], [4,3], [1,4], [3,6]]` -> indicates [index, cost] excluding 0 positions
cluster 2 = `[[5,2], [4,3], [2,5]]` -> indicates [index, cost] excluding 0 positions

Next I am picking the common index positions from both the clusters above which are : `[[5,2], [4,3]]` so here I have 2 common selections. This is removed from above arrays.

```
cluster 1 = [[0,3], [1,4], [3,6]]
cluster 2 = [[2,5]]
```

Since `m =3`, I need to select 1 position from cluster 1 and also 1 position from cluster 2.
As I need minimum cost, I am picking the first 1 occurrence from both the clusters:

```
cluster 1 = [0,3]
cluster 2 = [2,5]

So total cost is [5,2], [0,3], [4,3], [2,5]
so cost is = 2+3+3+5 = 13
```

My approach works only for limited input combinations

It cannot work for all possible combinations.

**Example: 2**

```
cost =      [3,4,5,6,30,200,10]
cluster 1 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
cluster 2 = [0,0,1,0,1,1,1]
```

Here the common index positions for both clusters with values 1 are `[4,5]` which have costs `[30, 200]` which sums to `230`

Based on my logic next selection will be index 0 from cluster 1 so cost is `230+3 = 233`
Then index `[2]` from cluster 2 so cost is `233 + 2 = 235`

But minimum cost can be achieved by selecting index positions as `[0,1,2,4,6]` (cluster 1 `[0,1,4]` and cluster 2 `[2,4,6]`, note: we can add cost for a common index position only once) = `(3+4)+(5+30+10)= 52`

So what is the correct approach to solve this?

**Constraints:**

```
m is in range 1 to 2*10^5
cost[i] in range 1 to 10^9
```

So in summary, in my approach, I am merging the elements by selecting common items from both the clusters after sorting by cost, then selecting other items from clusters.

Comment: Is there a web page for this problem? If there is, please give us the link. Unfortunately, I am not able to follow the example. The description in the problem web page may help.

Comment: This sounds like linear programming. Is it?

Comment: This is unrelated to Java.

Comment: You could create three sorted lists. One list has the common elements. The other two lists have unshared elements. Then it's just a three way merge.

Comment: @user3386109, I am already using merge operations by first selecting common elements and then selecting other elements. So i'm trying to understand  your comment, is it different from what I am thinking?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, I don't have the link.

Comment: By `merge`, I mean taking the three lists, and using an algorithm similar to the merge phase of a merge sort to select elements from those lists.

Comment: @tgdavies, I am trying to implement this in Java so I have added that tag initially.

Comment: Any chance you could give feedback to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76980505/5459839) of yours that I answered?

Comment: @trincot, sorry for delay, you provided a wonderful solution. If possible please check my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843148/find-longest-sum-for-array-and-given-days, this is blowing my mind, I am not able to understand how to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the challenge asks for selecting at least  items from both clusters, but it soon becomes clear that if you would have taken more than  from a cluster, you can certainly drop one. So we are looking for *exactly*   selections from both clusters. Each of these can either be a selection at 1 index (when both clusters allow that selection), or 2 indices. In the latter case we should only have to consider items that are available in only one cluster, not both (as that would not be optimal). So it makes sense to consider *pairs* of items from both clusters that are in that situation.

As the expected answer consists only of a total cost, it is not necessary to keep track of the indices in your intermediate arrays. You can just build up three (dynamic) arrays with only costs:

- The costs of items that are only available in cluster 1
- The costs of items that are only available in cluster 2
- The costs of items that are available in both clusters

Now you will want to repeat the following action  times:

- Check what the minimum values are in the first two arrays, and consider their sum (as this represents taking one item from each)
- Check what the minimum value is in the third array (as this represents taking one item from both clusters at the same index)
- Whichever is the minimum of the above two represents the best action to take: so add this cost to a total cost and remove those item(s) from the involved array(s)

To ensure enough efficiency, use priority queues for those three "arrays".

Here is an implementation in Java:

```java
    static int solve(int cost[], int cluster1[], int cluster2[], int m) {
        int n = cost.length;
        List<Integer> only1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> only2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> both = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (cluster1[i] == 1 && cluster2[i] == 1) {
                both.add(cost[i]);
            } else if (cluster1[i] == 1) {
                only1.add(cost[i]);
            } else if (cluster2[i] == 1) {
                only2.add(cost[i]);
            }
        }

        // Do a feasibility check: are there enough items available?
        if (Math.min(only1.size(), only2.size()) + both.size() < m) return -1;

        Queue<Integer> qBoth = new PriorityQueue<>(both);
        Queue<Integer> qOnly1 = new PriorityQueue<>(only1);
        Queue<Integer> qOnly2 = new PriorityQueue<>(only2);
        int totalCost = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            if (qBoth.isEmpty() || !qOnly1.isEmpty() && !qOnly2.isEmpty() 
                                   && qOnly1.peek() + qOnly2.peek() < qBoth.peek()) {
                totalCost += qOnly1.poll() + qOnly2.poll();
            } else {
                totalCost += qBoth.poll();
            }
        }
        return totalCost;
    }
```

Example run:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cost[] = {3,4,5,6,3,2,10};
        int cluster1[] = {1,1,0,1,1,1,0};
        int cluster2[] = {0,0,1,0,1,1,0};
        int m = 3;
        int totalCost = solve(cost, cluster1, cluster2, m);
        System.out.println(totalCost); // 13
    }
```